# Data warehouse one to many dim tables

Tags: one-to-many, data-warehouse

I'm creating a Data warehouse for the first time and not sure how to go about with my second 'many' table.  Where it's a dim, fact or even factless table.

So far I have two tables, Employee (one) and EmployeeAppLogin (many).
Both are SCD2 type.

dim_Employee is your typical HR employee dim table and EmployeeAppLogin which I think should store EmployeeAppKey (SK), EmployeeID (NK), loginName.  Or should it the employee_key (SK) from din_staff instead of EmployeeID (NK) from dim_Staff.

The EmployeeAppLogin  table is simply a look up table and holds no transactions.  It will be used to cross ref and identify an employee via the loginName on third party apps.  I haven't got access yet to the transaction tables from these third party apps.

So not sure where t fits in the DW.

Many thanks

Comment: Can an employee have multiple app logins?  Will you use any of the EmployeeAppLogin fields in your final reports (or is this simply an internal helper table)?

Comment: Yes, an employee will have multiple app logins.
It will be used to help idenify employees woth their login name against theie employee id.  i.e. a 'bridge' table.
The login name amd employee name will appear in the final reports.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create separate dimension tables for `Employee` and `Login`.  Report writers will be free to filter\aggregate by employee, login or both.

[image: Sample schema]

Data warehouses have a massive advantage over traditional databases.  The contents of every cell, row and column is under your direct control.  You are free to [transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load#Transform) the source data in any way you want.  For this reason, I design my dbs to be as easy to use a possible.  Because every single record passes through my ETL process, I can enforce relationships there.  The schema does not need to do this.

You will probably need a bridging table, to populate this structure.  But this can be hidden in your staging area.

The key benefit of this design is it provides you with a simpler, flatter structure.  I find this reduces the number of complex queries I have to write (which improves my productivity).  Flatter structures work better with data visualisation tools, like [Power Bi](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) and ad-hoc query tools, like [Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/analysis-services).

Comment: Thanks for that.  The login table in my productiond db will record the Employee ID, application Id, project id, and Login Name, of which an employee can appear multiple times.  So in my Dim set up I will require....

Dim_Employee (SCD2 EmployeeKey)
Dim_Application (SCD, ApplicationID)
Dim_Project (SCD1 project_ID)
Dim_Login(SCD2 ApplicationID, LoginName and LoginKey)
Fact_EmployeeApllicationLogin (EmployeeKey, ProjectID, LoginKey, other measurements to do with login data)

So i am stripping out all the IDs from the production db table and putting them into their own Dim tables?

Comment: As a general rule, yes. Certainly, the important data points deserve their own dim table. It provides a natural space to attach attributes (ex: Dim-App could contain `AppKey`, `AppName`, `AppOwner`, `AppCurrentVersion`, etc). Once you strip all the important ids, you may be left with a handful of unimportant / lesser used ids. These can be relegated to a [junk dim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(data_warehouse)#Junk_dimension), or squeezed into an existing dim (example: if no one really cares which app was used you could probably make it an attribute of dim login).